# Cassandra replication for big data

Tags: cassandra, replication

For now I need to use Cassandra replication(Master-Slave) topology, where slaves count about 1100. And I have some questions:

1. Are there any projects that use many slaves(about 1100) for Cassandra, PostgreSQL or Oracle?
2. Each slave need to contain only piece of all data from master(based on one property). In PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc. I might use "replication filters" for this. Is there an alternative in Cassandra?

Comment: Cassandra is not master-slave. All nodes are peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra replaces the master-slave architecture with a peer-to-peer one. It distributes data across each node [based on the partitioner](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_architecture/partitioning) used.

> Are there any projects that use many slaves(about 1100) for Cassandra, PostgreSQL or Oracle?

Not slaves but peers, but still, yep there are some projects with massive clusters... One of the more impressive C* clusters is described in the last [comment of this jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5351?focusedCommentId=13710119&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13710119).

> Each slave need to contain only piece of all data from master(based on one property). In PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc. I might use "replication filters" for this. Is there an alternative in Cassandra?

Again, master-slave is replaced by peer-to-peer, so no. But if you want to write to a master and then replicate it across to slaves isn't that a single point of failure?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Maybe you know alternatives of Cassandra(noSQL), where apply replication by piece - Riak, HBASE, MongoDB or another? And, maybe, you know big clusters with traditional SQL DB as PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Comment: As I see - CouchDb have replication filters and Master/Slave strategy. As anyone know - maybe any NoSQL have replication filters?